# gitignore all files/subdirectory in a directory but allow a readme.txt

Tags: git

Let's say this is my directory tree:

```
-root

--dir1

--dir2
```

the whole tree is a Git project, but `dir2` is special: the directory itself must be under Git, along with a `readme.txt` which explains the purpose of this directory. All other files, subdirectories and files-in-subdirectories must be gitignored.

I tired various combination without success:

```
/dir2/!readme.txt
!/dir2/readme.txt
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, if a file is already added into a repository, it's not covered by `.gitignore`. So if you (forcibly) add `dir2/readme.txt` into the repo, it will be tracked as usually, and you may put entire `dir2` into `.gitignore`.

Consider the following action log in a newly created repository:

```
tmp/git/repo3 $ git init   
Initialized empty Git repository in tmp/git/repo3/.git/
tmp/git/repo3 $ mkdir dir2                
tmp/git/repo3 $ touch file dir2/file
tmp/git/repo3 $ git status
On branch master                                    

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    dir2/
    file

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
tmp/git/repo3 $ echo "dir2/" >.gitignore
tmp/git/repo3 $ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .gitignore
    file

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
tmp/git/repo3 $ git add file .gitignore
tmp/git/repo3 $ git commit -m "initial commit"
[master (root-commit) d3b1044] initial commit
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+)       
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 create mode 100644 file
tmp/git/repo3 $ echo "this is readme" >dir2/readme.txt
tmp/git/repo3 $ git status # now check that readme.txt isn't tracked by git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
tmp/git/repo3 $ git add -f dir2/readme.txt # forcibly add the ignored file
tmp/git/repo3 $ git commit -m "Readme.txt"
[master d7a034b] Readme.txt             
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)                          
 create mode 100644 dir2/readme.txt

tmp/git/repo3 $ echo "A change to readme" >> dir2/readme.txt # now let's change readme.txt and make sure git status notices the change
tmp/git/repo3 $ git status                 
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)                
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory) 

    modified:   dir2/readme.txt                                             

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Answer (score 1):

The entries in your .gitignore file tells git if it should ignore these files and/or directories when reporting changes.

And you can manually add ANY file, independent of entries in .gitignore or not.

So, in your case, you should add the dir2 in your .gitignore, and then `git add dir2/readme.txt` as normal, which will get that file into git, and let git ignore any other changes in that directory.

Oh, and depending on in which order you make these changes, you may need to add the -f flag on your git add, to force the addition of the file into git, as it will complain because of the file being covered by the .gitignore settings.